# How to do Youtube live stream with text overlay (real time changing) dynamically in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, youtube, real-time

I am looking a solution to live stream a video with realtime text overlay on youtube channel in flutter for Android device.

Live stream process will be just like:

1. Capture video from camera
2. Show video on mobile screen
3. Add text (real time changing text) overlay at the bottom of screen just like cricket score / advertisement
4. Show final output video with overlay on Youtube

Kindly share your suggestion, if any.
Thanks a lot